# Can anyone help me with this issue - Django View (Passing of keys)

Tags: html, django, django-views

I have the following views:

```
def device_port(request):
    devices = Device.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        selected=request.POST.get('device')
        devices = Device.objects.get(pk=selected)        
        tablename = 'dev_interface_'+selected
        print("tablename: " +tablename)
        cursor=connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT interface FROM {tablename} WHERE id >=2")
        righttable = cursor.fetchall()         
        return redirect('/device/port/selected',{'devices':devices, 'selected': selected, 'righttable':righttable} )        
    return render(request, 'interface/device_port.html',{'devices':devices})

def device_port_selected(request, pk):    
    if request.method == "POST":
        job = JobForm(request.POST)
        device = devices.hostname
        print(devices)
        #job.associateddevice = devices.hostname
        try:
            selection=request.POST.get('portrange')
        except:
            selection = ""
            messages.warning(request, "Please select the ports")
        print(selection)
        #job.associatedinterface = selection
        return render(request, 'interface/device/port/selected/'+device+'.html',{'devices':devices, 'righttable':righttable} )        
    return render(request, 'interface/device_port_selected.html',{'devices':devices, 'selected': selected, 'righttable':righttable} )
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='interface-home'),
    path('device/', DeviceListView.as_view(), name='interface-device'),
    path('device_edit/<int:pk>/', views.device_edit, name='device-edit'),
    path('device_delete/<int:pk>/', views.device_delete, name = 'device-delete'),
    path('device_add/', views.device_add, name='device-add'),
    path('device/port/', views.device_port, name='device-port'),
    path('device/port/selected/', views.device_port_selected, name='device-port-selected'),
    path('device/routeport/', views.device_routeport, name='device-routeport'),
    path('interface/', views.interface_list, name='interface-list')
]
```

device_port.html

```
<form method="POST">
 <div class="form-row align-items-center">
  <div class="col-md-5 my-1">                                                 
   {% csrf_token %}
   <label for="Hostname">Hostname</label>
    <div class="input-group">
     <select id = "list" class="custom-select mr-sm-2"  onchange="getSelectValue();">
      <option selected>Select</option>
      {% for device in devices %}
       <option value={{device.id}}>{{device.hostname}}</option>
      {%endfor%}
      </select>
      <div class="input-group-append">                                                                            
       <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">Go</button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>                                                              
   </div>                                                                                                                  
  <input type ="text" name="device" id= "txtvalues" style="display:none">
</form>
```

So there are 2 page I am dealing with over here (`/device/port` and `/device/port/selected`). In this first page /device/port, user is required to pick a value from the drop down box and press the button Go. From here, it is intended to go to the next page which is `/device/port/selected` with the selected value in the first page pass to the next page.

But with the following code, I receive the error of

```
device_port_selected() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'
```

when moving from the first page to the next page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a context dictionary to a `redirect`. The second argument should be the URL arguments, not a context. So change the following line:

```
return redirect('/device/port/selected',{'devices':devices, 'selected': selected, 'righttable':righttable} )
```

to

```
return redirect('device-port-selected', pk=selected)
```

Note that it is better to use the name of the URL (i.e. `device-port-selected`) instead of the whole path as you can change paths in the future without affecting the rest of your code.